# Are any Marvel Universe superheroes or supervillains professional athletes?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe

Just out of curiosity, are there any superheroes or super-villains in the Marvel Universe who are excellent in sports?

By “excellent in sports”, I mean they must be playing a sport at a professional or recognized amateur level (i.e. as part of a national or international team, like an Olympic team).

For example, Ghostrider's alter ego is a professional stunt biker of national fame (I suppose).

All canons inclusive.

Comment: Taskmaster who switches between villain and hero as needed, used his ability to play sports at a high level. His ability is photographic reflexes which lets him replicate physical movement he sees, so when he was in high school he watched pro football to be the best quarterback.

Comment: To exclude: _Superheroes/super-villains fighting for money or fun_Superheroes/super-villains fighting for money or fun_. Why else would someone play sports if not for fun or money?

Comment: I'll have to agree with @Daft, you've excluded everything

Comment: I’ve attempted to make the question clearer. @GuruGalabKhatri: I *think* you’re asking whether any Marvel super-beings play professional sports (or sports that are technically amateur, but are in the real-world supported by sponsorships and are engaged in as someone’s full-time occupation, e.g. athletics). Let me know if I’ve misunderstood your meaning.

Comment: And although it doesn’t answer the question, [the guy who directed *Thor*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kenneth_Branagh) had a starring role in the 2012 Olympic opening ceremony.

Comment: The seems very broad. I appreciate it's likely to be a "finite list" but even so.

Comment: I agree, very broad. Everything can *technically* be a finite list.

Comment: Obviously any in universe sports association would Be very very anti meta human and would test extensively for it.

Comment: @cde: I dunno, the old Tour de France might not have minded that much.

Comment: And by for fun op means not supes who play pickup games at a local park,  and by for money, likely means not as underground black market illegal prize fighting

Comment: @Paul you mean the tour de france that stripped Armstrong of his 7 medals for blood doping?

Comment: @cde I think that's what he means by the "old" Tour de France. After all, how long did it take them to do that?

Comment: @KSmarts precisely. From what I understand, quite a few features of the way the Tour was run made substance abuse less obvious. The course changes every year, right? So it’s difficult to compare year-to-year to see whether performances are suspicious. And the tour relies somewhat on exciting finishes, which occur much more rarely without performance-enhancing drugs.

Comment: Does Spider-Man and the Hulk fighting Moleman at the Winter Olympics count?

Comment: Not a duplicate of that question! Completely different question and answers.

Comment: This question doesn't focus on Olympics... Sports of any level would suffice. So question can't be marked as duplicate.

Comment: @GuruGulabKhatri: sure, but you did ask if *any* superheroes/villains are excellent at sports. Thus if someone’s found one hero/villain who is, they’ve answered your question. And the Olympic question does that.

Comment: In the New Universe canon the leader of Kickers Inc. was a former pro football player.

Answer (score 16):

- [Northstar](http://marvel.com/universe/Northstar) secretly used his powers to win a gold medal in skiing in the Olympics.
- [Delroy Garrett](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delroy_Garrett) was an Olympic track medalist.
- [Hawkeye (Ultimate Universe)](http://marvel.com/universe/Hawkeye_%28Ultimate%29) is a former Olympic archer.
- [Calamity](http://marvel.wikia.com/James_Wa_%28Earth-616%29) was offered a contract to play major league baseball, but turned it down.
- [Bullseye](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bullseye_(comics)#Early_life_and_back-story) played Major and Minor League baseball until he decided to kill a batter out of boredom.
- [Boomerang](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boomerang_%28comics%29) was also a Major League pitcher.

Comment: hat tip to Jack B Nimble and Gnovice for their answers [on this question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/21155/who-was-the-first-dc-marvel-costumed-crime-fighter-credited-as-being-a-former-ol).

Comment: This probably should be made a wiki post. ..

Comment: @cde - why? Most people (make that 100%) can either edit or make edit suggestions. Wiki isn't necessary anymore due to the latter

Comment: Bruce Wayne probably could have *bought* a football team, but that's a little different, isn't it...

Comment: @corsiKa Yes, especially since Bruce Wayne is from DC, not Marvel.

Comment: @phantom42 I'm crushed. When I asked this question, I only got 4 upvotes.

Comment: Kickers Inc. (New Universe) Leader was a former pro football player